# How to index versioned column of HBase table in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, hbase

I am using HBase as big data store for real-time access of individual record(s) and Solr for searching data stored in HBase.

I want to add versions to a column of HBase table so that it can also hold previous values. For example, I set parameter **VERSIONS => 5** for column **cust_info:address** so as to keep last five addresses of customer.

I have created an equivalent field in **schema.xml** file of Solr collection as shown,

```
<field name="address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I search for a record in Solr, it shows only latest updated value of address. I want to do searching in all five addresses of customers.

How can I index and store this multi-version column of table in corresponding Solr field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative stratey for doing same thing with HBase and solr. Instead of adding versions to a column **cust_info:address**, add multiple columns in Hbase as required. Since HBase is schema-free, you can add as many columns as you want in a column-family. Add columns **cust_info:addr1, cust_info:addr2, cust_info:addr3, cust_info:addr4, cust_info:addr5** to insert five addresses if they exist.

In Solr, create a dynamic field in **schema.xml** file, as shown

```
<dynamicField name="addr*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now there will be five fields in Solr document as **addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4, addr4, addr5**. You can search in all these fields.

**OR**

If you don't want to create multiple address fields like **addr1, addr2,...** you can do it with copyField as following:

1. Create a multiValued field, e.g, `address`
2. Create a dynamic field `addr*` that will match all fields beginning
   with `addr`
3. Create a copyField that will copy all fields matching with `addr*`
   to `address` field

E.g.

```
<field name="address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<dynamicField name="addr*" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

<copyField source="addr*" dest="address"/>
```

This way makes querying much easier than previous one because you have to search only in single field `address`.